# How to define a full text index for sqlite in Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, rails-migrations

The following migration for sqlite:

```
class CreateCeDicts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ce_dicts do |t|
      t.string :hant
      t.string :hans
      t.string :pinyin
      t.string :english
    end
    add_index :ce_dicts, :hant
    add_index :ce_dicts, :hans
    add_index(:ce_dicts, :english, type: :fulltext)
  end
end
```

gives an error:

> SQLite3::SQLException: near "fulltext": syntax error: CREATE fulltext
>   INDEX "index_ce_dicts_on_english" ON "ce_dicts" ("english")

as `:fulltext` is [only supported for MySQL](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index).

How can I define [a sqlite fulltext search index](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_2) in Rails migration?